# Why transaction blocking simple insert in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, innodb, php, phpmyadmin

## transaction Query

```
    mysqli_begin_transaction($conn);
    $sql = "UPDATE foldertable SET trashed = 1 WHERE serverToken = (SELECT serverToken from servertoken where userToken = ? limit 1) and 
    
    (folderId = ?
    or 
    RootFolderPath LIKE 
                CONCAT (
                    (SELECT RootFolderPath FROM foldertable WHERE serverToken = (SELECT serverToken from servertoken where userToken = ? ) AND folderid = ? limit 1)
                    ,'/'
                    , ?
                    ,'%'

                )
    )";
    $stmt =  mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sisii", $data["userToken"], $id, $data["userToken"], $id, $id);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
        echo mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
        $serverError = true;
        return;
    }
    // echo "\n\n affected rows " . mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0) {
        sleep(15);
        // Insert into bin folder
        $sql = "INSERT INTO binfolder (serverToken , folderId) value ( (SELECT serverToken from servertoken where userToken = ? limit 1) , ?)";
        $stmt =  mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $data["userToken"], $id);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
            echo mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
            $serverError = true;
            return;
        }
        if (mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0) {
            $success = true;
            mysqli_commit($conn);
        }

    }
```

## Insert Query

```
INSERT INTO foldertable(serverToken) SELECT (123456)
```

## Problem

if execute the insert query  after transaction started but the insert does not have to wait for transaction complete . Because the update query on transaction does lock row involved with insert query.

## What I wanted

the Insert query will run immediately if it does not contain the same `serverToken` needed in Insert query.

Thank You in Advance.

[image: foldertable structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For transaction blocking, the first line of defense is to speed up the query.  Though this does not completely eliminate the possibly of block/delay/deadlock, it will often make the situation more tolerable.

Re the `LIMIT 1` -- Is there only 1?  If so, why not do a `JOIN`.  Or might there be more than one?  If so, which one?  That is, don't you need an `ORDER BY`?

`servertoken` needs `INDEX(userToken, serverToken)`

Would a single `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` suffice for your lengthy set of queries?  If so, it would probably be a lot faster.

I see an `OR` in the long query.  This is likely to prevent usage of an index.  (I don't understand the intent of the query well enough to suggest an alternative.)

"RootFolderPath LIKE CONCAT (..." -- This smells like something that should be redesigned.  Consider putting path parts in separate columns?  Or something else.

Is `folderId` the `PRIMARY KEY` of `folderTable`?

Plese provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (as text, *not* image) for each relevant table.

Comment: Yes folderId is my primary key